# Cant set config caching options in a local config?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm working on setting up config caching in a zf2 application. Putting the settings in application.config.php seems to work fine...

```
// config/application.config.php
'module_listener_options' => array(
    'module_paths' => array(
        './module',
        './vendor'
    ),
    'config_glob_paths' => array(
        'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php'
    ),
    'config_cache_enabled'     => true,
    'config_cache_key'         => 'my_cache_key',
    'module_map_cache_enabled' => true,
    'module_map_cache_key'     => 'my_cache_key',
    'cache_dir'                => '/var/www/appsuite/html/data/cache/'
)
```

but if I put those same options in a local config `config/autoload/application.config.local.php` the cache files arent being created. Is the caching happening before local configs are merged? Our sop is to have *.local.php configs for environment specific configurations rather than relying on environment variables, is that possible with config cache configs?

Comment: What does your index.php look like? Or, show me the code where you're instantiating Zend\Application. Usually you pass it the contents of your application config, you need to glob and merge if you want local application configs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the application configs don't support the use of the `.local` and `.global` naming conventions. The usual way to get around this is to use environment variables as documented [here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/tutorials/config.advanced.html#environment-specific-system-configuration).

However if you want to support the `.local` naming convention we can differ from that implementation slightly by continuing to use environment variables but doing something like this in our index.php

```
if (getenv('APPLICATION_ENV') == 'development') {
    $app_config = 'config/application.local.php';
} else {
    $app_config = 'config/application.global.php';
}

Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require $app_config)->run();
```